# Order in groups on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
"Project nr"    "Task"                "Task deadline"  "Task Type Production"

456             pack                  1 april 2013      Pack
456             Leave production      3 april 2013      Leave Production
456             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date

123             pack                  1 april 2013      Pack
123             Leave production      6 april 2013      Leave Production
123             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date

789             pack                  1 april 2013      Pack
789             Leave production      9 april 2013      Leave Production
789             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
```

Hi, below my present Query. How can I display it in three rows sorted by date on leave production in a way that they stay in groups of 3. Like above. The p[roject ID numbers must stay in groups and the groups mus be sorted on leave production.

```
    SELECT MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
    ,max(CASE WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Packed' THEN [Task deadline] END) AS Pack
    ,max(CASE WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production' THEN [Task deadline]
    END) AS [Leave Production]
    ,max(CASE WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date' THEN [Task deadline]
    END) AS [Flight Date]

    FROM MSP_EpmProject_UserView LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView ON 
    MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID LEFT JOIN
    MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = 
    MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmResource_UserView ON 
    MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
    WHERE (MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskIsProjectSummary = 0) GROUP BY 
    MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `UNPIVOT` such as the example below:

```
SELECT  [Project nr], Task, TaskDate
FROM    (
        SELECT   MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
                ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Packed' 
                            THEN [Task deadline] 
                        END) AS Pack
                ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production' 
                            THEN [Task deadline]
                        END) AS [Leave Production]
                ,MAX(CASE   WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date' 
                            THEN [Task deadline]
                        END) AS [Flight Date]
        FROM    MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
                LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
                    ON MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID 
                LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView 
                    ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID 
                LEFT JOIN MSP_EpmResource_UserView 
                    ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
        WHERE (MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskIsProjectSummary = 0) 
        GROUP BY MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
        ) data
        UNPIVOT
        (
          TaskDate
          for [Task] in ([Pack],[Leave Production],[Flight Date])
        ) piv
ORDER BY    data.[Task deadline]
```

Comment: Hi, Tried it but I get an error on the order by clause:           Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @Anne Updated answer - Try moving the ORDER BY so that it's outside the main query.